# How to display ME language in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Hello i am trying to add some text to pdf using itextsharp (me language - hebrew, arabic) but the text is shown in reverse. the code is

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Server.MapPath("~/StudioFonts/EFT_Beigale Heavy.ttf"),
                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                Font EFT_Beigale_Heavy = new Font(bf, 12, Font.BOLD, CMYKColor.CYAN);

                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.CYAN);
                cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 30);
                cb.SetTextMatrix(60, 60);
                cb.ShowText(pageContext);
                cb.EndText();
```

any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Hebrew/Arabic isn't supported for `ShowText()` in old iTextSharp version. See my comments to your other question. If you don't upgrade to iText 7, you only have RTL support in `ColumnText` and `PdfPTable`!

Comment: It seems a little strange :-( What developers was doing until iText7? there is no way to write from right to left with old itextsharp version?

Comment: Er... Why are you making me **repeat three times** that RTL (required for Hebrew/Arabic) in iText 5 **is supported** in `ColumnText` and `PdfPTable`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie , Bruno that what i was asking in this issue, how to set ColumnText or PdfTable for hebrew in itextSharp :-) any help will be great.

Comment: I have spent days, weeks, no: *months* writing documentation, so why not use it? See [run direction](http://itextpdf.com/tags/run-direction) on the official web site. Take a look at [the examples of the books I wrote](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11) about iText. Your questions depress me because if you'd claim there isn't sufficient documentation, you make me feel that I have been wasting my time spending all that work on those examples.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you very much for your patient :-) working great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BrunuLowagie Thanks for patient and support
this is the working code

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Server.MapPath("~/StudioFonts/EFT_Beigale Heavy.ttf"),
BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font EFT_Beigale_Heavy = new Font(bf, 40);
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
column.SetSimpleColumn(20, 200, 300, 36);
column.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
column.AddElement(new Paragraph(pageContext, EFT_Beigale_Heavy));
                column.Go();
```

Comment: Deserved upvote for posting the update. This is useful for further reference.